# "Invalid namespace" by retrieving ProcessorId through wmic

Tags: namespaces, cmd, indexing, processor, wmic

I do not understand why the cmd command

```
wmic cpu get ProcessorId
```

works on 2 of my 3 computers

On the third is returning

"Invalid namespace"

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try running "wmic cpu list /format:list". My guess would be it is a different version of wmic and the name of the variable is different. That command should give you a list of what you are able to get with the wmic cpu call.

Comment: WMI is Windows Management Instrumentation. It's part of Web Based Enterprise Management (WBEM) and lives in c:\windows\system32\wbem.






See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation



You can see these resources. They are all advanced.



WMI Diagnosis Tool



Read about version 2

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404265.aspx



Here's version 2.1 for download

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7684



More about repair

http://windowsxp.mvps.org/repairwmi.htm

.
--